# Parent and Child bullet in Python

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a document which contains the following sample text,

```
This is a document which contains parent and child
    •   Photosynthesis
        •   CO~2~ in
        •   H~2~0 in
        •   Sunlight in
    •   Glucose
        •   CO~2~ in
        •   C~6~H~12~O~6~
        •   Oxygen out
```

How to separate those parent and child bullets in Python,
I used **python-docx**

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('bullet_test.docx')
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    text = p.text.encode("utf-8").strip()
    style = p.style.name.strip()
    print style
```

I am getting style as **'List Paragraph'** and I can't able to get it as **'List Bullet' or 'List Bullet2' or 'List Number'**

Comment: You are using strip which removes trailing spaces

Comment: @DarkSuniuM It will remove trailing spaces in List Paragraph but my expectation is that print List Bullet

Comment: Are you sure the document actually has those Styles?   Maybe it's just got an indent and a "•" character ?

Comment: Yes @Kingsley I created the document by using the bullet style manually.

Comment: @DuraiSankaran actually you don’t apply the bullet style to your paragraph but you change the paragraph format locally. Visually, this is the same but the style of your paragraph hasn’t change, only its format.

Comment: Actually, I created a document by using Microsoft Word document, I tried to read it from python-docx. Here I didn't change any paragraph format

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you bullet lists are styled with the “List Paragraph” style which is one of the [built-in Microsoft Word styles](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdBuiltinStyle.html). And, the style applied to each of the paragraphs is modified locally to turn it into a bullet list (of different levels). So you can’t guess the level from the style itself, you need to inspect each paragraph format (bullet, tabulation, etc.).

The formatting properties of a paragraph are accessed using the [ParagraphFormat](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.parfmt.ParagraphFormat) object available using the paragraph’s [paragraph_format](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.paragraph_format) property.